# Any good reason to restore the original accessiblity value after changing it?

Tags: java, reflection

When accessing a non-visible field or method using reflection, it seems to be a common idiom to restore the original accessibility value after changing it:

```
Field field = ...
boolean origAccessibility = field.getAccessibility();
field.setAccessibility(true);
try {
  // access field
} finally {
  field.setAccessibility(origAccessibility);
}
```

I wonder if there is a good reason to restore the original accessibility state. I see the following cases:

- *Compiled code* cannot access the field anyway.
- *Code that accesses a non-visible field using reflection* would also call setAccessible(true)
- *Code that uses reflection just to query the method's accessibility* would potentially get the wrong result anyway, while the try block is executed.

I tend to think that resetting the original state is useless. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not necessary.

All `field.setAccessible` does is update the single reference you are using to address the field (the one you put in your `field` local variable). It does not have any lasting effects. The next time someone else calls `clazz.getField` or whatever, they get a fresh object back (even when talking about the same field).

Comment: In some unit test, I changed some static field with reflection. This override persisted on another classes :s. I will replicate the issue and post a question